# Changing the button image in one section changing the other also?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am loading two types cells in a table view from two different custom classes.I have 5 sections in my table view each having single rows.I am added one button to my cell and when clicking on it it will change the image of the button .as button.selected=YES;ike that.But my problem is when i am scrolling the cells r repeating,ie  if i selected a button in a row then the background image of that row only need to change.But in my case some cell buttons are also changing.Here is how i am adding the things.`

```
- (UITableVieCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"CellIdentifier";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell";
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row==0)
    { 
         CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
            cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"dhjkhs.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];


        }
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.datelabel.text=@"skhfkhdf";
      cell.nameLabel.text=@"dsdbjsbjf";
    cell.msg.text=@"dshjshhshd";
 [cell.lbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(callAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     
  cell.myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sdsd.png"];
  cell.llabel.text=@"sdjkjskljdls";   
        cell.llabel.tag=indexPath.section+1;

        return cell;

    }
    else 
    {


        Customcellwithimage *cell = (Customcellwithimage *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[Customcellwithimage alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];
             cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"sdsdsd.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
        }
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.datelabel1.text=@"sdsdsdsd";
        cell.nameLabel1.text=@"sdsdsdsdsd";
        cell.msg1.text=@"sdsasfkdakfhk ";

         [cell.likebutton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(callAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
        cell.myImageView1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"jpg1.png"];
         cell.cellview1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"adsdsd.png"];

        cell.llabel1.text=@"sdsdsdsdl";
        cell.llabel1.tag=indexPath.section+2;
       cell.bannerview1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dsdsd.png"];

        return cell;







    }



    return Nil;

}
```

`i have 10 sections each returning 1 row.My problem is i need to change the image of the button when clicked.I was adding that button in the customcellwith image class as`

```
[lbutton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sdsd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[lbutton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sdsdsd.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
lbutton1.selected=NO;`
```

and in my code i have added `

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
      button.selected=YES;
```

` But the problem here is it also changing the button in another section also.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand the problem, but I think you want to move background creation also behind the if. Once it will be changed you should reset it and they way it is now it won't be reseted (just like you reset selection style you should reset background)

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
}

cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"dhjkhs.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.datelabel.text=@"skhfkhdf";
cell.nameLabel.text=@"dsdbjsbjf";
cell.msg.text=@"dshjshhshd";
[cell.lbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(callAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     
cell.myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sdsd.png"];
cell.llabel.text=@"sdjkjskljdls";   
cell.llabel.tag=indexPath.section+1;

return cell;
```

Comment: actually it would be best to create the image only once and cache it, not create it every time, but first lets check if this is a problem here; btw thanks for edit sunkehappy

Comment: You are welcome. And `imageNamed:` will cache the image by the system. Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some problem with your check condition for `if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row==0)`. This check will always `NO` when it's not the first section. So your cell will not be reused for your class `CustomCell` except for your first section's first row.

Comment: but actually my problem is when i click on the button on the second row i am changing its image.But at the same time the button in the 4 th row also changing

Comment: You say 'But at the same time the button in the 4 th row also changing'? At the exactly same time? No scroll when the 4th row's button change?

Comment: I mean if you have scrolled after you tap a button. Maybe the reason is your button is reused(the state is also reused).

Comment: so can u help me how can i use it efficiently

Comment: I'm not sure. You can set `cell.lbutton.selected = NO` in your table view's datasource delegate method. That is to set it to normal when reuse that button. Have a try.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19886/discussion-between-sunkehappy-and-angry-developer)

Comment: but in that case the changed button also changed to its normal..again